# Android - mockito stub simple variable (not method)

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I have a class with multiple variables inside.

`SomeViewModel` has a boolean variable defaulted to `false`,

```
var booleanVariable = false
```

`SomeViewModel` depends on `SomeDataModel`,

```
var dataModel: SomeDataModel? = null
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class TestClass {

  @Mock lateinit var someViewModel: SomeViewModel
  @Mock lateinit var someDataModel: SomeDataModel

  @Before
  fun setup() {
    when(someViewModel.booleanVariable).thenReturn(true)
    when(someViewModel.dataModel).thenReturn(someDataModel)
  }

  @Test
  fun shouldShowImportPolicyTest() {
    someViewModel.booleanVariable // return FALSE, not true as stubbed
    someViewModel.dataModel // always returns NULL
  }
}
```

if I stub a method it works fine. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post here the implementation of `booleanVariable` and `dataModel`.

Comment: I updated. it's basically member variables

Answer (score 0):

You can mock member variables if they are not final with Mockito.

You have 3 choices here:

1. make them `open`
2. use the dependency `mockito-inline` to allow the mocking on final classes/fields
3. use the Kotlin `all-open` compiler plugin to make the class and its fields `open` in tests (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html)